# Only fire the event on the correct User Control

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

I have the following Scenario, I have a `TabControl` where each `TabPage` represents a Year. On every Year-`TabPage` I have another `TabControl` with 12 `TabPages` which are the Months. On every Month-`TabPage` I have a `UserControl`. I do that like this:

```
foreach (TabPage tp2 in tbMonat.TabPages)
            {
                ucMonat Monat = new ucMonat(Convert.ToInt32(tp.Name), Convert.ToInt32(tp2.Name));
                Monat.Parent = this;
                OnSetUrlaub += Monat.getSelectedCells;
                Monat.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                tp2.Controls.Add(Monat);
            }
```

On my MainForm I have a `Button`, if that `Button` is pressed a `Event` is fired on the `UserControl`. But at the Moment the event is fired on every `UserControl`. I just want it to be fired on the currently active `UserControl`. How can I do that?

**MainForm:**

```
public delegate void SetUrlaub(string Date, EventArgs e);
    public event SetUrlaub OnSetUrlaub;

public void cmdUrlaub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (OnSetUrlaub != null)
            OnSetUrlaub(Jahr + Monat , e);
    }
```

**UserControl:**

```
public void getSelectedCells(string sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Year = Convert.ToInt32(sender.Substring(0, 4));
        int Month = Convert.ToInt32(sender.Substring(4));

        int numCells = this.dgvUrlaub.SelectedCells.Count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event Handlers aren't selective in that way. Every subscriber will receive the event when its raised and all of your usercontrols subscribe to the same event.

You can either filter when you receive the event

```
if (this.Focused)
{
   //Do stuff only the active control should do
}
```

Or you can unsubscribe and subscribe as the focus changes, by subscribing to the user controls `Enter` and `Leave` events

```
Monat.Enter += (s, e) => OnSetUrlaub += ((ucMonat)s).getSelectedCells;
Monat.Leave += (s, e) => OnSetUrlaub -= ((ucMonat)s).getSelectedCells;
```

So that only the active `ucMonat` gets the event.

Comment: Is the Subscribe/Unsubscribe Part in the `foreach`? If so, I get an Error saying: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: @E-Nuff Sorry, slight syntax error from not using an IDE

Comment: I used the first approach